# "Block if without end if" error VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I tried looking through the other answers, but nothing really seemed to help me out.  As the title states, I'm getting a "Block if without end if" error.  I'm trying to put in a conditional statement that ends the sub if its met.  To be more specific, I'm formatting data that can only be formatted one job at a time.  I want to automatically end the sub if it determines there are multiple jobs in the spreadsheet.  Here's what I've got so far.

```
Sub SUBNAMEHERE

(Lots of other code)

JobNo = (code that figures out how many jobs there are)
If JobNo > 1 Then
    MsgBox (warning message)
    End Sub
End If

(The rest of the code)
```

If anyone could help me out, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: not `End Sub` but rather `Exit Sub`

Comment: Try `Exit Sub` rather than `End Sub`.

Comment: These both worked, thank you kindly.  This was a pretty dumb oversight from someone who doesn't know code that well.

Comment: Don't be too hard on yourself, I'm sure many programmers will be familiar with losing hours due to a ; or a : or something ridiculous. I lost half a day due to SMS needing to be written as 'sms' in Android despite what the docs said! I've actually made this same mistake within the last few weeks, no better way to learn really! My new job requires me to write tons of VBA which I know next to nothing about and things like this are a regular occurrence. You'd be surprised how much better you get after a few weeks! Good luck!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `Exit Sub` rather than `End Sub`.

When you say `End Sub`, you're telling VB that you're done defining the routine.  So if you haven't ended the `If` before that, it'll be considered incomplete.

Course, even if you *did* end the `If` before that, you'd almost certainly wind up getting errors about code outside of a function.  (I don't know VBA all that well..but that's how most flavors of VB work.)

Answer (score 2):

```
Sub SUBNAMEHERE

(Lots of other code)

JobNo = (code that figures out how many jobs there are)
If JobNo > 1 Then
    MsgBox (warning message)
    -------> End Sub  <------ 
End If

(The rest of the code)
```

The End Sub should go on the bottom of the Sub

---

And as your the commentors pointed out, it's `Exit Sub` that you're looking for.